# dafny sequence to multiset

Tags: proof, dafny, multiset

While trying to make some assertions about sequences and subsequences I came to realize that dafny does not seem to prove this statement. I don't know how it could not be true. Should I just make this an axiom and move on or this there a way to prove this to dafny?

```
lemma multisetSequence(nums: seq<int>, ms: multiset<int>) 
    requires |nums| > 0
    requires multiset(nums[1..]) == ms;
    ensures multiset(nums) == ms + multiset{nums[0]}
{
    assert forall i :: 1 <= i < |nums| ==> nums[i] in ms;
    assert forall i :: 1 <= i < |nums| ==> nums[i] in multiset(nums);
    //the following fails, which breaks my brain
    assert forall i :: 1 <= i < |nums| && nums[i] != nums[0] ==> multiset(nums)[nums[i]] == ms[nums[i]];
    if nums[0] in ms {
        assert multiset(nums)[nums[0]] == ms[nums[0]]+1;
    }else{
        assert ms[nums[0]] == 0;
        assert multiset(nums)[nums[0]] == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going down a rabbit hole. The issue is simply sequence extentionality on `nums`:

This verifies for me:

```
lemma multisetSequence(nums: seq<int>, ms: multiset<int>) 
    requires |nums| > 0
    requires multiset(nums[1..]) == ms;
    ensures multiset(nums) == ms + multiset{nums[0]}
{
  assert nums == [nums[0]] + nums[1..];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think to assert that first. I guess it seemed obvious.

Comment: it *is* obvious!! but it's one of those sharp edges in Dafny that it will basically never attempt to prove this kind of fact on its own. the reason is simply that empirically, we tried it ("we" being Rustan), and it made everything way too slow. so instead, any time you want Dafny to "notice" that a sequence breaks apart like this, you have to say so explicitly. just one of those things you learn from experience with the tool